# Array values in recursive mapped types

Tags: typescript

I have a mapped `Draft` type as such:

```
export type Draft<T> = {
  -readonly [P in keyof T]: Draft<T[P]>;
};
```

When I use that to wrap an array I am no longer able to call instance methods:

```
const arr: Draft<Array<number>> = [];
arr.push(42); // Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'Draft<(...items: number[]) => number>' has no compatible call signatures.
```

Is there a way to make my `Draft` type copy call signatures? If I change `-readonly [P in keyof T]: Draft<T[P]>` to `-readonly [P in keyof T]: T[P]` I am able to call methods but then `Draft` doesn't recursively apply itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution based on the official implementation of [`DeepReadOnly<T>`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/d4dc67aab233f5a8834dff16531baf99b16fea78/tests/cases/conformance/types/conditional/conditionalTypes1.ts#L120-L129):

```
export type DraftObject<T> = {
  -readonly [P in keyof T]: Draft<T[P]>;
};
interface DraftArray<T> extends Array<Draft<T>> { }
export type Draft<T> =
  T extends any[] ? DraftArray<T[number]> :
  T extends ReadonlyArray<any> ? DraftArray<T[number]> :
  T extends object ? DraftObject<T> :
  T;
```